Why are Lottery Odds Calculated Differently When a Bonus Number is Included or Not?
Ok, I can't get my head around this, but here goes:
The UK Thunderball is a 5 out of 39 + 1 out of 14 type lottery.
The US California Fantasy 5 is a 5 out of 39 type lottery.
The odds (as stated on the webpage) for the Fantasy 5 is $1:575,757$ to hit 5 out of 5. Fair enough. This can be calculated like this (correct me if I'm wrong):
$$\frac{39!}{5!\times34!} = 575,757$$
Now, the second prize for the UK Thunderball is hitting 5 out of 39 without hitting the Thunderball (bonus, which is drawn from another pool or set).
The question is: Shouldn't hitting the 2nd prize UK Thunderball (5 out of 39) equal the exact same odds as the 1st prize Fantasy 5?
Suppose I aimed at the Thunderball 2nd prize, completely disregarding the Thunderball (bonus). Since it's drawn from a separate pool, it shouldn't affect the odds of the main pool. Why then does the UK Thunderball state the odds of winning the 2nd prize (5 out of 39 and no Thunderball) as a different $1:620,046$?
Can someone please make sense of this? I've seen the same happening on other lotteries worldwide, where the bonus is drawn from another pool. That is, lotteries whose first prize theoretically equals another lottery's second prize have different odds (per their websites), where the only difference is a bonus number drawn from another set.
Why?
Thanks!

Notice that your odds 1:620,046 written as a fraction is equal to 1:575757 times 13/14. Do you see what I'm hinting at?

Note that the "official" odds, given here for instance, work as you would expect for the top prize, for which they correctly state the odds as $1$ in $14\times \binom {39}5$.  So...the bonus choice is not ignored, rather it is broken into the two cases.

The Fantasy 5 website states: Odds 1 in 575,757. The Thunderball website states 1 in 620,046.

Yes, but you aren't understanding the rules.  The second prize is for getting the $5$ main correct AND the bonus wrong.  The first prize is for getting the $5$ main correct AND the bonus right.  Despite your claim, the bonus is not ignored.

So, what you're basically saying is 575,757 * (14/13) = 620,046, which includes the 13 out of 14 odds of not getting the bonus, correct?

Exactly.  I have posted it below.  I posted it as a "community" solution since, as I just noticed, @Immi  has noted the same thing.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
For setting the "official" odds, the bonus is NOT ignored.  Rather the top prizes are split into two cases, according to whether you guess the bonus correctly or not.
Thus, the first prize requires you to guess all six numbers correctly, which gives you a chance of $1$ in $14\times \binom {39}5=8060598$ just as you would expect.
However, the second prize also takes the bonus into account, by assuming you got that one wrong.  Thus the probability it sites are really $13$ to $14\times\binom {39}5$  or one in $\frac {14}{13}\times \binom {39}{5}=620,046$ as they quote.
